# How can we specifically use the data comes from the api in the map function?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am creating a Facebook copy by using react and redux. I get my post data from API (json-server). In each post, I have a post-menu button. And when I click it, it opens the post-menu. However, because I use my data in the map function, when I click the post-menu icon, it opens all of the posts' post-menu. Before telling what I tried, let me show my codes.

**ACTION TYPE**

```
export const OPEN_POST_DROPDOWN = "OPEN_POST_DROPDOWN"
```

**ACTION**

```
export function openPostDropdown() {
    return { type: actionTypes.OPEN_POST_DROPDOWN, payload: null }
}
```

**STATE**

```
isPostDropdownOpened: false,
posts: []
```

**REDUCER**

```
case actionTypes.OPEN_POST_DROPDOWN:
    return {
       ...state,
       isPostDropdownOpened: !state.isPostDropdownOpened
    }
```

**UI**

```
clickHandler() {
        this.props.actions.openPostDropdown()
    }

{posts.map(post => (
         <div key={post.id} className="post mt-3">
                <div className="post-header">
                    <div className="post-name-and-pp-area">
                        <div className="post-pp-area">
                            <img src={post.post_owner_pp} alt="user-pp" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="post-user-area">
                            <span className="post-user-name">{post.post_owner}</span>

                            <div className="post-time-and-public-area">
                                <span className="post-time">{post.post_time}</span> · <i className="fas fa-user-friends"></i>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>

                            <i onClick={() => this.clickHandler()} className="fas fa-ellipsis-h post-menu"></i>

                            {isPostDropdownOpened ? <PostMenu post={post} /> : null}
                        </div>
.
.
.
```

There is no error in the project but I couldn't find a solution about how can I manage the thing when clicking it, just showing one post-menu.

I tried to copy my posts state into an array-like

```
post_array = Array(post.length).fill(null)
```

But then I stumbled later.

Events also couldn't help me handle this problem. I couldn't find educational content for this situation on the Internet.

How can I make specific operations in data or anything in the map function?

Comment: Did you try with id id. Mean pass the specific id to click handler which you want to open

Comment: I also thought using id but couldn't manage the function side of it. Would you mind showing it please ?

Comment: call function like this this.clickHandler(post). and recieve that post in function like this clickHandler() {
        this.props.actions.openPostDropdown()
    }. and set in state this post and use outside from map this {isPostDropdownOpened ? <PostMenu post={post} /> : null}

Comment: Thank you so much @arslan. Although I didn't understand your last 'outside from map' sentence, because I understood what you tried to say, I came up with a solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I GOT SOLUTION**

1.

```
 currentActivePost: null
```

2. 

```
clickHandler(post) {
        this.props.actions.openPostDropdown(post)
}
```

3. 

```
export function openPostDropdown(post) {
    return { type: actionTypes.OPEN_POST_DROPDOWN, payload: post }
}
```

4. 

```
case actionTypes.OPEN_POST_DROPDOWN:
            return {
                ...state,
                isPostDropdownOpened: !state.isPostDropdownOpened,
                currentActivePost: action.payload
            }
```

5. 

```
{isPostDropdownOpened && post.id === currentActivePost.id ? <PostMenu post={post} /> : null}
```